# Custom Rollup in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, average, multidimensional-array, rollup

I have created in SSAS a cube that represents “the value of counters measured from network element in a period of time” so the structure of the cube will be as follow:

Dimensions:

```
    - Time
    - Counter 
    - Network Element (a parent-child dimension)
```

Fact :

```
    - Value: which represent the numeric value measured of the counter
```

For some counters, I must do the rollup of the value by calculating the average.

I’m using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, I tried to create a column in the dimension Counter to hold the MDX expression of the custom rollup so the expression to perform the average rollup by the dimension Network element (NE) for the counter [433] will be:

```
Avg([NE].[NE Parent SK].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN, ([Measures].[Value],[Counter].[Counter SK].&[433]))
```

[Measures].[Value]: is the fact.

When I browse the cube this counter is disappeared which mean it has the NULL value.

I tried to use calculated member [Average] which is calculated as follow:

```
[Measures].[Value]/[Measures].[Value Count]
```

[Measures].[Value Count] is a default measure caculated by SSAS.

Then I put in custom rollup column this MDX expression:

```
[Measures].[Average]
```

When I browse the cube this counter is disappeared which mean it has the NULL value.

My second problem is : how can I perform two different rollup calculation with each  dimension (in my case: time & Network Element)